# user login error unicode object not callable

Tags: python, django, unicode

I created MainUser model and this model has **unicode** method, but here I have problem like **'unicode' object is not callable**

this my authorization function:

```
def auth(request):
    params = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            login = request.POST['login']
            password = request.POST['password']
        except:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'empty fields')
            return redirect(reverse('main:sing_in'))
        user = authenticate(username=login, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('main:work')
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('main:sing_in'))
    return render(request, 'sing_in.html', params)
```

and this one my mainuser model:

```
class MainUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
        django user model
    """

    login = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, unique=True,
                             db_index=True, verbose_name=u'Логин')

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=222, blank=True,
                                  verbose_name=u'Имя')

    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=222, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=u'Фамилия')

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=u'email')

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MainUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'login'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def full(self):
        return {
            "first_name": self.first_name,
            "second_name": self.second_name,
            "email": self.email
        }

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.login

    def get_full_name(self):
        return u"{0} {1}".format(self.second_name, self.first_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.login)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Пользователь"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Пользователи"
```

I can't understand where bug in the code, it give error when i call login(request, user)

Comment: `login` is a `unicode` string, you tried to call it. You assigned a string with `login = request.POST['login']`, then tried to call it with `login(request, user)`.

Comment: `login(request, user)` - there is no function `login` in your code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and what I must to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've redefined `login` to be the variable that stores the data from your field. Call it something else.